# How can I check if a line in a file has information or not in Python 3.6?

Tags: python

I am trying to create a memory set, saved in a separate text file stored in a different location. I have tried to use some of the suggestions on this site, but maybe my code is different. I am using Python 3.6.
Here is my code:

```
df = open("Memory.txt", 'r')
askforfname = df.readlines()
df.close()
print (askforfname)
if '\n' in open("Memory.txt", 'r').readlines():
    df.close()
    name = input("What is your name?: \n")
    Bigname = name.title()
    df = open("Memory.txt", 'w')
    df.write(Bigname)
    df.close()

else:
    df = open("Memory.txt", 'r')
    returning_name = df.readlines()
    print("Welcome back" + str(returning_name))
    df.close()
```

I am using print(askforfname) in the fourth line just to make sure the data is being read from the proper line, and it is. But it just skips over the if command, as if it came out false, and continues right the the else command, even if the line is blank. I am just a beginner in programming, and don't know much, so i don't know if I'm just making a simple mistake lol. And yes, I understand my code must be inefficient, but since I am new, this is just me experimenting with code.

Comment: What is this code supposed to do?

Comment: Have you looked at what is in the result of `open("Memory.txt", 'r').readlines()`?

Comment: @mentalita is supposed to check if in the programs memory file, it has your name stored in it already.

Comment: @StevenTautonico `'\n' in open("Memory.txt", 'r').readlines()` will return `False` if your file is empty. It will return `True` only if your file has one blank line. Empty file and file with a blank line are different.

Comment: @ScottHunter yes, in the fourth line of code, i have a print command that prints the result of the first line of code, and it comes out as [] in the output if nothing is there. I tried to check for "[]" in the if command, but it still results as false.

Comment: @StevenTautonico For an empty file, `print(open("Memory.txt", 'r').readlines())` will give you `[]` whereas for a file with blank line, you will get `['\n']`.

Comment: @MusafirSafwan Thank you so much, I added something to the second line,  but how would I check if only the first line is empty, and if this is a stupid question, I'm sorry, I'm a beginner at coding :(

Comment: @StevenTautonico Then the result of `open("Memory.txt", 'r').readlines()` will be like this: `['\n', 'Safwan']`. So check whether the first element in this list is `'\n'` or not. You can get first element by using `open("Memory.txt", 'r').readlines()[0]`.

Comment: @StevenTautonico: So you knew that `askforfname` was an empty list, and asked why your `if` statement didn't find a `\n` in it, and went to the `else` part?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let `names.txt` be a simple `.txt` file with a few names in it:

```
ken
dennis
guido
bjarne
```

Say you're `Bjarne` and want to check whether your name is in the file. Probably the most efficient approach would be not to read the file into memory at all, but rather lazily get its contents. Apart from that, you would be better off using `with` context manager, instead of manually managing closing your file objects like that:

```
myself = 'Bjarne'

with open('names.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        if myself.lower() in line:
            print('Here am I!')
        else:
            print('No, this is not me')
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `Memory.txt` file is an empty file and the result of `if condition` will be `False`. You need to have at least a blank line in your file for `if condition` to return `True`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, inefficient, but also harder to read and understand with repeated opening and line reading.  Please to not post such code.

.readlines produces a list of strings representing lines, terminated by \n *if* the line in the file is so terminated.  Your test is correct, if obscured.

```
>>> '\n' in ['']
False
>>> '\n' in ['a']
False
>>> '\n' in ['a\n']
False
>>> '\n' in ['\n']
True
```

It must be that your file does not contain a blank line ending with a newline.

Answer (score 0):

First, there must be something in Memory.txt.
'\n' indicates a blank line in the file.
There is already a very clear example, I'm giving you some tips：

1. If the file is large, you can read multiple times, limiting the
   size of the file each time it is read to ensure it does not take up
   too much memory:

> ```
>  name = Jack
>  with open('Memory.txt', 'r') as f:
>      while True:
>          content = f.read(2048)
>          if content == '':
>              break
>          else:
>              if name.lower() in content:
>                  print('name is here')
>              else:
>                  print('name is not here')
> ```

2. If this file is small, the memory can hold the contents of the file, you can use readlines() and read().